# ReactJS component state does not change as expected

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-state

I created a `Container` class and an `InnerElement` class. Where the `Container` wraps the `InnerElement`s. It is necessary to show just a single `InnerElement` at a given time.

The problem appears, when I change to another `InnerElement`. Interestingly when I create a `console.log` it displays the changed element but it is not rendered. Could someone give me a hint please, thanks in advance!

`Container` class:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Container extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.changeElement = this.changeElement.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            currentElement: 0,
        }
    }

    changeElement() {
        const nextElement = this.state.currentElement + 1;
        this.setState({currentElement: nextElement});
    }

    render() {
        const element = this.props.children[this.state.currentElement];
        // In the console log the next (correct) element is shown
        console.log(element);

        return (
            <div>
                {element}
                <button onClick={this.changeElement}>next element</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Here the `InnerElement` class:

```
import React from 'react';
export default class InnerElement extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            name: props.name ? props.name : "test"
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.name}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

And here my `Container` with `InnerElement` call:

```
<Container>
    <InnerElement name="A" />
    <InnerElement name="B" />
    <InnerElement name="C" />
    <InnerElement name="D" />
</Container>
```

I also discovered, that it works, when I use in the `InnerElement this.props.name` instead of the state.

Comment: Axnyff makes a good point, but I would also ask why you are trying to put *name* on state instead of just using *this.props.name*?

Comment: @Kevin my application is a lot larger and it contains some component specific state information like a changed input text, etc. The given one, is just a simple example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React have trouble determining your children is changing with your `setState` because you are dynamically modifying the children. To help React do this, you can add a key to your InnerElement:

```
<Container>
  <InnerElement key="A" name="A" />
  <InnerElement key="B" name="B" />
  <InnerElement key="C" name="C" />
  <InnerElement key="D" name="D" />
</Container>
```

Comment: Thank your for the hint, is their any literature to this topic?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys it's not very explicit but as you are dynamically accessing children, React can't statically determine what has been changed.